# Redirect user if they enter from page other than Index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET core Razor engine. I want make sure if the user goes to any other page (cshtml file) besides the index page have them redirected to the index page.

The Index page is where the user logs in.  My strategy is *display the users first name on each page*. If the *first name is null* redirect to the Index page.

I am having the issue on how to redirect, or is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
 <h1>Hello @TempData["first_name"] @TempData["last_name"]</h1>
 @if(TempData["first_name"]!=  null)
 {
     @{Response.Redirect("~/Index");
 }
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use action filters.

Comment: You don't redirect from a *view*, you redirect from the *controller*.  Or, in the event of wanting to perform the same redirect logic in many places (which it sounds like in this case), you can add something more universal to the middleware (an action filter, as suggested above) so that it's performed by default on all actions.

Comment: @Aaron How do you authenticate user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) combined with [forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx).

> **Using AuthorizeAttribute**
>
> When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and authorized. If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action methods in the controller are restricted. Within a controller that is marked with the AuthorizeAttribute attribute, you can use the AllowAnonymousAttribute attribute to specify that a particular action method is not restricted to only authorized users.
>
> The Authorize attribute lets you indicate that authorization is restricted to predefined roles or to individual users. You use the Roles and Users properties to specify which roles or users are permitted to access the action method. This gives you a high degree of control over who is authorized to view any page on the site.
>
> **If an unauthorized user tries to access a method that is marked with the Authorize attribute, the MVC framework returns a 401 HTTP status code. If the site is configured to use ASP.NET forms authentication, the 401 status code causes the browser to redirect the user to the login page.**